# warning: cannot find entry symbol PPCIS_REV_A; defaulting to 00040000

Tags: u-boot

I am compiling my codes on U-boot,i am using Makefile to compile, i had encountered below mentioned warning.
ppc_4xx-ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol PPCIS_REV_A; defaulting to 00040000

Makefile:
    ppc_4xx-ld -g  -Ttext 0x40000 \
                -o PPCIS_REV_A -e PPCIS_REV_A main.o init.o nand2/NandFlash2.o UART/sio.o GUI_COMM/pkt.o RTC_NVRAM/RTCNVRAM.o \
        UART/serial.o UART/serial_baudrate.o 1553B/ace1553b.o DDR_RAM/memtsts.o DDR_RAM/mem.o GUI_COMM/commands.o \
        ADC/ADC.o NVRAM/NVRAM.o DISCRETE/Discrete.o USB/USB.o RELAY/Relay.o FLASH/Flash.o RPM/rpm.o libstubs.a\
                -L/opt/eldk/ppc-2008-04-01_amcc/ppc_4xx/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/powerpc-linux/4.2.2 -lgcc

```
powerpc-linux-objcopy -O srec PPCIS_REV_A PPCIS-MOD2_REV_A.srec 2>/dev/null

powerpc-linux-objcopy -O binary PPCIS_REV_A PPCIS-MOD2_REV_A.bin 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Unfortunately your post lacks the necessary information to reproduce the issue: Which version of U-Boot do you refer to? For which defconfig file do you try to build? What toolchain are you using?

Comment: i am using u-boot-1.1.6

Comment: U-Boot 1.1.6 is seven years old. Mainline U-Boot 1.1.6 does not contain any string 'PPCIS_REV_A'. So that string must be either from your code or from some vendor code.